# updated to PHP 7 and got all my php.ini link to php_curl.dll instead of curl.so

Tags: php, php7

I have recently updated my server and it forced a PHP update from PHP 5 to 7.

I got all my php.ini files point to .dll files (php_curl.dll for example) and not to curl.so. (it's pointing to the files in /var/lib/php/20131012/ where all the files there are .so - which make scence).

Can that cause any other problems in the future with other things (like fork, which was installed in the previous php5 and now doesn't work).

What is mostly recommended to do in this case in the best secure way for not messing up my server (although the feeling that it's messed up already).

Running the query after this edit outputs an error an my email file: `/var/mail/root` which says:

> /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean: 12: /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean: php5: not
>   found

What is going on??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get old php.ini settings after I updated to PHP7 and created a new folder with new php.ini files](http://askubuntu.com/questions/766858/how-to-get-old-php-ini-settings-after-i-updated-to-php7-and-created-a-new-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/usr/lib/php5/sessionclean: 12: /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean: php5: not found
```

I just updated php on my Debian and had the same error. Check if you fully deleted php5, I had to manually uninstall package `php5-common`. (Package php5 was however uninstalled automatically by `dist-upgrade`)

Comment: Thank you so much I have been trying to figure out what was wrong with the code and settings of the PHP where nothing didn't seem wrong. This solved my problem!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to comment all extensions with .dll restart apache and see if it works. Mine was resolved after doing so. Don't forget to backup your php.ini file